# Pytorch dataloader: data shape issue with custom COCO dataset for model finetuning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I have an object detection task for which I prepared images and annotations*. The objective to is fine-tune an existing model with Pytorch. Images (PNGs) are stored in the same folder where the COCO json annotations are stored. The json annotations use the [Object Detection](https://cocodataset.org/#format-data) COCO format:

```js
"info": {...},
 "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "width": 4961,
            "height": 3508,
            "file_name": "somefile.png",
            "license": 1,
            "coco_url": null,
            "date_captured": null
        },
        ...
 ],
 "annotations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image_id": 1,
            "category_id": 3,
            "segmentation": [[4372,2830], [4803,2830],[4803,3131],[4372,3131]],
            "area": 129731,
            "bbox": [4587.5,2980.5,431,301],
            "iscrowd": 0
        }, ...
],
"categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "someCategoryName",
            "supercategory": "someSuperCategoryName"
        },
        ...
],
"licenses": [...]
```

I need to read this dataset to fine-tune an existing model. This is how I'm opening it:

```
# By default, define a transform to convert PIL image to a Torch tensor
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.PILToTensor()])
train_dataset = dset.CocoDetection(root=dataset_path, annFile=annotationFilePath, transform=transform)
```

I'm then defining a Data Loader as follows. The dataloader `next()` function works fine:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=lambda batch: tuple(zip(*batch)))
images, targets = next(iter(train_loader)) # check that `next()` works
```

The content of `images` and `targets` objects is like this:

```json
images: [tensor([[[255, 255, ...rch.uint8), tensor([[[255, 255, ...rch.uint8)]
targets: [{'id': 265, 'image_id': 265, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [...], 'area': 1726288, 'bbox': [...], 'iscrowd': 0}]
```

In particular, note that **`targets`** is a list of dictionaries, where *each dictionary retains the shape of the `annotations` entry* in the json (see the code snippet).

Finally, I test if the `model` function can actually run, with:

```
model = models.detection.fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn(weights=torchvision.models.detection.FasterRCNN_MobileNet_V3_Large_FPN_Weights.COCO_V1)
output = model(images, targets)  # check if `model()` works
```

However, this always raises:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This error comes from the `forward()` method of `generalized_rcnn.py`, [because it expects a  "boxes" key entry when iterating the `targets`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/d80d5bd21c6ee677af50d39689ba7005645b7ef4/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L64C20-L65).

Now, I would have expected the `DataLoader` to appropriately shape the `targets` for them to work with the `forward()` method, given that I'm using a COCO dataset. Why isn't that so? What should I do to make it work? I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation.

* <sub>For completeness: to label, my company needs to use a specific PDF annotator. Therefore, I wrote my own converter from that output to get a COCO-shaped dataset. There may be something incorrect in the COCO json annotations I obtained, but I personally do not think this error is related to that.</sub>